# get url() to translate the alias

Tags: uri

Ok, I have my own menu on my multilingual site. I have a page with the alias "about" in english. And english is my default language. So, when I am browsing the site in spanish I would like the spanish alias. I have tried all combinations I can think of to get the url() fucntion to translate "about" to "acercade",as it is in the system. What would be the correct way? Is it even working?

> url('about',array=("absolute"=>TRUE, "alias"=>TRUE)) ;

thats my best guess.

Thanks for any hint,
Michael

Answer (score 3):

No need for `$options['alias'] = TRUE`, that will prevent alias lookup.

> If you provide an internal path and $options['alias'] is set to TRUE,
>   the path is assumed already to be the correct path alias, and the
>   alias is not looked up.

Use the `node/$nid` path and let Drupal find the correct alias.

If that doesn't work, you could try manually passing the `$options['language']` parameter

> 'language': An optional language object. **If the path being linked to
>   is internal to the site, $options['language'] is used to look up the
>   alias for the URL.** If $options['language'] is omitted, the global
>   $language_url will be used.

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/url/7

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Ok, so when I do the following: `url('node/6', array( "language" => language_list()['es']));` what i get is */es/node/6*. So while this works technically, I do not get the translation, which would be better for search engines.

Comment: is it possible that it is a problem that the translation in spanish (es) does not have node-id 6 but 8?